# Use unions with Form data in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'd like to implement a FastAPI endpoint which requires different FormData fields based on `grant_type` argument:

```py
@dataclass
class DeviceTokenGrant:
    grant_type: Literal["urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"] = Form(const=True)
    client_id: str = Form()
    device_code: str = Form()


@dataclass
class RefreshTokenGrant:
    grant_type: Literal["refresh_token"] = Form(const=True)
    refresh_token: str = Form()
```

I couldn't find an example in FastAPI docs how to make this work and keep `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` media type instead of `application/json`. Is there a way to specify a union type for these formdata parameters?

I've tried to add a union with `Depends`, but it raises an error:

```py
async def token(grant: DeviceTokenGrant | RefreshTokenGrant = Depends()) -> TokenResult:
```

The error says:

```
TypeError: auth.api.oauth.DeviceTokenGrant | auth.api.oauth.RefreshTokenGrant is not a callable object
```

If I replace it with `Union`, then the schema is replaced with `args` and `kwargs` arguments:

```py
async def token(grant: Union[DeviceTokenGrant, RefreshTokenGrant] = Depends()) -> TokenResult:
```

[image: schema]

Comment: Why are you using `@dataclass` and not `pydantic.BaseModel`?

Comment: `pydantic.BaseModel` classes don't seem to work correctly with `Depends` and `Form` attributes. If I use `BaseModel`, I get HTTP422. If it's a dataclass, then everything works as expected. https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/5588

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with the solution for this, but it looks a bit hacky - I extend `params.Form` class and disable the `embed` field. Then unions start to work with `BaseModel`:

```py
from fastapi import params

class FormClass(params.Form):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(**kwargs)
       self.embed = False


class DeviceTokenGrant(BaseModel):
    grant_type: Literal["urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"]
    client_id: str
    device_code: str


class RefreshTokenGrant(BaseModel):
    grant_type: Literal["refresh_token"]
    refresh_token: str


async def token(grant: Union[DeviceTokenGrant, RefreshTokenGrant] = FormClass()): ...
```